# executing return statement in Java

Tags: java, return

My desired output is to print 
You are in the main method
@@@@You have declined to use this application under our terms
please try again later
But my return statement doesn't print anything
What Am I missing? Here is my code

class demo
{
         String applicationOutput(int eeter)
    {

```
    if (eeter == 1 )
    {
    System.out.println("You have opted to use this application underour terms");
        return "success and come";
    }
    else
    {
     System.out.println("@@@@You have declined to use this application under our terms");
        return"please try again later";

    }

 }
```

}
 class demo1
    {

```
 public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("You are in the main method");

demo d = new demo();
d.applicationOutput(0);
        }
}
```

Actual O/p;
You are in the main method
@@@@You have declined to use this application under our terms

Comment: without a print, it won't print

Comment: without discarding the return , how can I print the return?

Comment: The return value is saved in `d.applicationOutput(0);`. So you could do something like `String x = d.applicationOutput(0);` and then print that String or print `d.applicationOutput(0);` directly.

Comment: Appreciate your Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main you need to add the print element.

```
System.out.println(d.applicationOutput(0));
```

I advise you to have one return in your method, something like this:

```
String applicationOutput(int eeter) {
    String messageReturn = "";
    if (eeter == 1 )
    {
       System.out.println("You have opted to use this application underour terms");
       messageReturn=  "success and come";
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("@@@@You have declined to use this application under our terms");
        messageReturn = "please try again later";

    }
    return messageReturn;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in main

```
System.out.println(d.applicationOutput(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main method ignores the return value of `applicationOutput`. If you want to print it, you'll have to do it there:

```java
System.out.println(d.applicationOutput(0));
```